# JSDoc3 how to let it know a variable is a reference to a Class prototype

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I've got the following javascript class setup;

```
/**
 * @class
 * @constructor
 */
var Klass = function() { ... }

var p = Klass.prototype;

/**
 * Set custom options
 * @param {object} options - options
 */
p.setOptions = function(options) {
    ...
}
```

How do I make JSDoc recognize the 'p' shortcut variable as the Klass. If I use 'Klass.prototype' instead of 'p' it recognizes the setOptions method perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a method tag, and prepending the classname to it.

```
/**
 * Set custom options
 * @method Klass.setOptions
 * @param {object} options - options
 */
p.setOptions = function(options) {
   ...
}
```